# How to split this string properly?

Tags: java, string, split

I'm looking to split a string input by the user that has to be presented in the following format:

```
integer*integer
```

If I use the `.split("\\*")` method to create an array using the asterisk as the delimiter, it works just fine, I end up with an array of two elements, which is what I'm looking for.

However, if the user enters something like (note the spaces):

```
integer *integer 
or
integer * integer
or 
integer* integer
```

To be more precise, this is the exact snippet that doesn't seem to be working:

```
String formatChecker = input.next();
System.out.println("LENGTH:" + formatChecker.split("\\*").length);
```

and an example

```
1*1
LENGTH:2

1 * 1
LENGTH:1
```

the `.split("\\*)` only yields an array with one element, and I have no idea why. The problem only appears when the delimiter is next to a space, but from what I understand it should still provide a two element array, the only difference would be that the strings would have spaces in them but that can be cleaned up easily using .trim() .

Any help on a foolproof way of obtaining a two element array from this string using .split() would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: [This](http://ideone.com/PnmHRq) says otherwise.

Comment: You are right. I am editing my post to be more precise, as I still couldn't find an explanation for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `input` is a `Scanner`, [`Scanner#next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--) used here

```
String formatChecker = input.next();
```

tokenizes on whitespace, by default (it's really on the delimiter pattern). In other words, if you input

```
1 * 1
```

and press the enter key, it will only return

```
1
```

So it's not `String#split(String)` that is broken, it is your input reading strategy. Perhaps consider using `Scanner#nextLine()` to read everything until a new line character.